# Extract each RGB layers from raster and paste into matrix in R

Tags: r, image, matrix, raster

I would like to store a raster image into an empty matrix. I load my image and I create an empty matrix of same dimension.

```
setwd("C:/Users/Desktop/image/")
img_path <- "image.jpeg"
raster <- brick(img_path, package="raster")
nrow <- dim(raster)[1]
ncol <- dim(raster)[2]
img_matrix <- matrix(, nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol)
dim(raster)
[1]  896 1408    3
dim(img_matrix)
[1]  896 1408
```

When I try to load the raster into the matrix I got this error:

```
img_matrix[1, 1] <- raster
Error in img_matrix[1, 1] <- raster : 
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I think the problem is there are 3 layers in the raster and the matrix is just 1. So I think I create 3 matrix and paste each R, G, B layer of the raster into the associated matrix. Finally, assemble the 3 matrix to create the image.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `as.array` method for objects of class `raster`.

```
library(raster)
raster <- brick("3.jpg", package="raster")
dim(raster)
#[1] 665 800   3

array <- as.array(raster)
dim(array)
#[1] 665 800   3

array[201:205,401:405,1]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]  244  244  244  244  244
#[2,]  244  244  244  244  244
#[3,]  244  244  244  244  244
#[4,]  244  244  244  244  244
#[5,]  244  244  244  244  244

array[201:205,401:405,2]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]  202  202  202  202  202
#[2,]  202  202  202  202  202
#[3,]  202  202  202  202  202
#[4,]  202  202  202  202  202
#[5,]  202  202  202  202  202
```

As you can see, this will coerce the raster object into a three dimensional array.

Comment: ok great. I can do this for each layer:   ll <- as.matrix(array[,,1])
  img_matrix[,] <- ll

Comment: Indeed you can.

Comment: next step input this in a loop with overlapping